# does specman have static variables?

Tags: static, specman

I have the following code in specman that I inherited:

```
some_method() is {
    var a: bool;

    if (!a) {
        a = some_other_method();
    };
};
```

My understanding is that each time `some_method()` is called, `a` is generated anew, and there's no sense in checking `a`'s value before it's assigned.  However, it may be that I'm missing something here.  For instance, if `a` is static then this code makes sense, which brings me to my question:

Is there any way for a variable to be static in specman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are no static variables as in C. A variable in a method has its default value (`False` in this case) if not initialized, so you should be right `if (!a)` should always be `True`.

Things would be different if `a` was a struct member, then like in other OO languages it would retain there value over several method calls and the check would make more sense:

```
struct some_struct_s {
    a : bool;
    some_method() is {
        if (!a) {
            a = some_other_method();
        };
    };
};
```

You can check stuff like this also on the interactive prompt:

```
Specman> var a : bool;
Specman> print a
  a = FALSE
```

There the interactive help is also nice, for example try:

```
Specman> help variable
```

and select the entry (by number) `sn_eref: variables : declaring`. There you will find all relevant information for your question.

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Static struct members (events, fields, methods) were added to the language in Specman v15.2. A static field can't be generated, physical(%) or used in when subtypes.

```
struct some_struct_s {
    a : bool;
    some_method() is {
        if (!a) {
            a = some_other_method();
        };
    };
};

-- Change field 'a' for all instances
on xxx { some_struct_s::a = TRUE; };
```

Here's some comments from the teamspecman blog : [Static members in e](http://cadence-fv.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=3180846&item=247)